# Using Puppeteer, how would you map through an array of links where it would go to the first link in the array close that tab, and repeat?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, web-scraping, puppeteer

I currently have it where it goes to the first link that i put in as follows

```
(async () => {
  let funkoUrl = "https://www.cardboardconnection.com/brand/funko/funko-pop";
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
  });

  let page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(funkoUrl), { waitUntil: "networkidle2" };
```

I then run this code to get the array of links that i need to go to

```
let links = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let url = document.querySelector(
      "#productListing > div:nth-child(1) > div.brandproductDescription > h2 > a"
    ).href;

    links = Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll(
        "#productListing div.brandproductDescription > h2 > a"
      )
    ).map((link) => link.href);

    return links;
  });
  console.log(links.length);
```

the links.length = 745 links to go to. I then need to open each link seperately, where i can scrub the data and then close that tab AND then go to next link in array. Currently it will open up all the tabs at once and then idle out of me or crash server.

I currently have this to handle the array of links

```
links.forEach(async (link) => {
    try {
      const newPage = await browser.newPage();

      await newPage.goto(link);

      const data = await newPage.evaluate(() => {
        const headline = document.querySelector("h1").innerText;

        const titles = Array.from(
          document.querySelectorAll(".entry h3")
        ).filter((title) => title.innerText !== "");

        const pageData = titles.map((title) => ({
          title: title.innerText,
          image: title.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.querySelector(
            "img"
          ).dataset.src,
        }));

        return (data = {
          headline,
          pageData,
        });
      });

      console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } finally {
      await newPage.close();
    }
    console.log(link);
  });
```

What else could work is instead of getting an array of links, clicking the first link and opening that up in a new tab, scrubbing the data, closing the page, then clicking on the second link on the page for the next link i need to go to and repeating that. Any ideas on how to make this work effeciently?

Answer (score 2):

Using await in a forEach loop doesn't work as you would expect and thats why it is opening all of the links at once, instead try using a for..of.

```
for(let link of links){
    try {
      const newPage = await browser.newPage();

      await newPage.goto(link);

      const data = await newPage.evaluate(() => {
        const headline = document.querySelector("h1").innerText;

        const titles = Array.from(
          document.querySelectorAll(".entry h3")
        ).filter((title) => title.innerText !== "");

        const pageData = titles.map((title) => ({
          title: title.innerText,
          image: title.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.querySelector(
            "img"
          ).dataset.src,
        }));

        return (data = {
          headline,
          pageData,
        });
      });

      console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } finally {
      await newPage.close();
    }
    console.log(link);
}
```

Comment: Tiny corrections: 1. If `links` is not an array of Promises, there is no need for `await`, just `for (let link of links){` will do. 2. Maybe there is no need to open and close a new tab/page each time, the same page may suffice.

Comment: I agree with @vsemozhebuty, you could use the same page.